# how to get issue type name by issue type id in SIL script? (besides of of SQL request to DB)

Tags: jira

I use createIssue() routine in my script. This routine gnneeds the issue type name as an input.

To make the script resistant to issue type renaming I'd like to put issue type id instaead of issue type name in it. I know how to find out the id, but do do not the convinient way to transform it to name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrote a SIL routine, getting issue type name from Jira REST API

```
function getIssueTypeNameById(int issueID) {
    string uname = "username";
    string pwd = "password";
    HttpRequest request;
    HttpHeader header1 = httpBasicAuthHeader(uname, pwd);
    request.headers += header1;
    string url = "https://<domain>/rest/api/2/issuetype/" + issueID;
    struct issueName { string name; } 
    issueName issName = httpGet(url, request);
    return issName;
}
```